# "process.arch" returns wrong value when Node script is run through Ruby

Tags: javascript, node.js, ruby, terminal, apple-m1

On my Mac with an Apple M1 chip, in a Node script, `process.arch` returns `arm64` as expected, with the following code in `script.js`:

```js
console.log(process.arch);
```

Then, I run the Node script through Ruby, with:

```rb
`/usr/local/bin/node "script.js"`
```

Where the backticks run the command in the terminal, and returns the output. But this time, it outputs `x64`.

How can I force `process.arch` to return `arm64` instead, when ran through Ruby? I tried the following, but it wouldn't let me override the read-only property of `arch`:

```js
process.arch = 'arm64';

console.log(process.arch);
```

I need to get `process.arch` to output `arm64`, rather than use any workarounds, because I am using some popular Node packages that call `process.arch`.

Comment: Looks like ruby is using Rosetta, as such when it spawns I assume it's going to run that inside Rosetta too.  So I wonder if you can use the arch command line, I don't have an M1.  But maybe this will work -> `arch -arm64 command`

Comment: Have you updated your Ruby, too? Check with `gem env`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue, thanks to the help of the comment from Keith, regarding using the `arch` command with arguments.

Essentially, where I previously had:

```rb
`/usr/local/bin/node "script.js"`
```

I now have:

```rb
`arch -arm64 /usr/local/bin/node "script.js"`
```

And it works perfectly.